# SSIS dtexec when are spaces in path name

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to run a SSIS package using dtexec

My package is deployed to a folder which has spaces in the path name

This is casuing dtexec to spit out the dummy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the path to the file in double quotes.